# Break out of ajax loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a function that loops through a list if items and then for each item it makes an ajax call to an external api.

This all works fine both calling it in a loop and individually. But what I want to do is to give the user the option to cancel the requests at any time. When the list is small (about <20) the process is done in about 2-3 seconds which is fine. But sometimes the list can be several hundred which can take several minutes to run and I want to give the user the option to cancel out of this at any time.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getData(myList)">Get All Data</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelProcessCalls()">Get All Data</button>

<div ng-repeat="item in myList">
    <div>
        <div>{{item.Id}}</div>
        <div>{{item.Name}}</div>
        <div>
            <span ng-bind-html="item.statusText"></span>
            <span ng-bind="item.Data"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The angular/jquery code is:

```
$scope.getData = function (itemList) {
    if (itemList != null) {
        $.each(itemList, function (index, item) {
            $scope.getItemData(item);
        });
    }
};

$scope.cancelProcessCalls = function () {
    $scope.processCalls=false;
};

$scope.getItemData = function (item) {
    if ($scope.processCalls) {
        if (item != null) {
            item.statusText = "Getting data...";

            $.ajax({
                url: _url + item.Id,
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .fail(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $scope.handleError(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                item.Data = data;
            })
            .then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            })
            .always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                item.statusText = null;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

So the first function just loops through the list and makes a call for each item.

I have tried adding in a variable that checks whether to continue with the calls but that doesn't work because it is all wrapped in a scope of work.

Is there a simple way to cancel or break out of that loop elegantly?

Comment: why do you do multiple ajax calls in the first place?

Comment: Store all the ajax requests in an array, when cancel is called loop around them and call the [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) method on them

Comment: @madalinivascu - because there are multiple records to loop through. I could just pass a list to a backend process and have that loop through, but right now the existing process works perfectly fine without the cancel ability. I am not going to re-design the entire process, just thought there was a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. The idea is that you store the xhr object in an array and then when you want to cancel you loop around the array and call abort on the request.

```
$scope.requests = [];

  $scope.getData = function(itemList) {
    $scope.cancelProcessCalls();
    if (itemList != null) {
      $.each(itemList, function(index, item) {
        $scope.getItemData(item);
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.cancelProcessCalls = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.requests.length; i++) {
      $scope.requests[i].abort();
    }

    $scope.requests.length = 0;
  };

  $scope.getItemData = function(item) {
    if ($scope.processCalls) {
      if (item != null) {
        item.statusText = "Getting data...";

        var xhr = $.ajax({
          url: _url + item.Id,
          method: 'GET'
        });
        $scope.requests.push(xhr);

        xhr.fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $scope.handleError(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
          })
          .done(function(data) {
            item.Data = data;
          })
          .then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {})
          .always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            item.statusText = null;
            $scope.$apply();
          }););
    }
  }
```

Comment: I get the following error:
Object doesn't support property or method 'abort'
when it gets to the line
$scope.requests[i].abort();

Comment: Just about to update my code in the answer but check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvtx1sb7/1/) for the working code

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I couldn't even work out how to create a fiddle to reproduce the issue!

Comment: works perfectly! I had to make a small change to the handleError function as that was catching all the aborted calls, thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.breakCheck = false;
$scope.getData = function (itemList) {
    if (itemList != null) {
        $.each(itemList, function (index, item) {
            if ($scope.breakCheck) {
              return;
            }
            $scope.getItemData(item, $scope);
        });
    }
};

$scope.cancelProcessCalls = function () {
    $scope.processCalls=false;
};

$scope.getItemData = function (item, scope) {
    scope.breakCheck = true; // You can move this line anywhere to decide when you want to stop the ajax
    if ($scope.processCalls) {
        if (item != null) {
            item.statusText = "Getting data...";

            $.ajax({
                url: _url + item.Id,
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .fail(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $scope.handleError(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                item.Data = data;
            })
            .then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            })
            .always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                item.statusText = null;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: you have just added a variable called breakCheck where I've already got that in place called processCalls which does the exact same thing?

Comment: Does it work? If it does, you can look into cleaning it up. If not, please post the error/what is going wrong

Comment: no, it's the exact same as I have at the moment. I moved the breakCheck variable into the cancelProcessCalls method but it still loops through. It only updates the variable value at the end unfortunately